# Wrong recursion when trying to find Range Sum of BST

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

I'm practicing algorithms and tackling this classic problem. There are many solutions and I'm trying to solve it using Javascript. I'll post the question and what I have below:

> Given the root node of a binary search tree, return the sum of values of all nodes with value between L and R (inclusive).
>
> The binary search tree is guaranteed to have unique values.
>
> ```
> Example 1:
> Input: root = [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], L = 7, R = 15 Output: 32
> ```

```
var rangeSumBST = function(root, L, R) {
    let result = 0;

    if (root === null) return 0;
    if (root.val >= L && root.val <= R) {
        result += root.val
    }
    rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R)
    rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R)

    return result
};
// Output is 10 instead of 32
```

Comment: how does the tree look like? please add the tree.

Comment: Tree looks like this: [10,5,15,3,7,null,18], so 10 is the parent node with 5 and 15 as the children. 3 and 7 are children of 5, and null and 18 are chilren of 15

Comment: It is tree traversing. But what about tree code?

Comment: not 100% sure, this is from a leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst

I realized I'm not adding anything to sum, that's the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing `rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R)` without using result from them. And finally get only first node value. Use instead:

```
var rangeSumBST = function(root, L, R) {
    let result = 0;

    if (root === null) return 0;
    if (root.val >= L && root.val <= R) {
        result += root.val
    }
    let left = rangeSumBST(root.left, L, R)
    let right = rangeSumBST(root.right, L, R)

    return result + left + right;
};
```